# How do I count unique values in the index of a pandas pivot_table?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

Given a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'player': ['James', 'Henry', 'Abe', 'James', 'Henry', 'Brian', 'Claude', 'James'],     
    'team': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C'],
    'game': [101, 102, 103, 101, 102, 104, 105, 101],
    'score': [10, 11, 12, 10, 11, 10, 12, 10]
})
```

I can create a pivot_table that summarizes by player and team, with game as the column and summing the score:

`pd.pivot_table(df, index = ['player', 'team'], columns = 'game', values = 'score', aggfunc = 'sum', fill_value = '')`

This returns a table like this:

[image: pivot_table output]

What I want to do, though, is to count the number of unique teams each player played on, so that Abe, Brian and Claude all have 1, Henry has 2, and James has 3.

I've tried nunique and count_values but they seem only to work with numbers, not strings. I've seen questions that address the problem of counting unique values in the 'values' part of the pivot table, but not in the index part.

Edit -- here is the desired output, note that the game scores are still summed:

[image]

Comment: can you provide your desired output in text table?

Comment: @PandaKim -- I'm trying but when I add it to the OP I get an error that I can't resolve about entering code that isn't formatted correctly (though I didn't change the code)

Comment: @PandaKim -- ironically, Stack Overflow renders my table correctly in preview but won't let me save the edit. So I did a SnagIt of the rendered results table and added it to the post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update my answer

**Code**

```
out = (df
       .assign(unique_teams=df.groupby('player')['team'].transform('nunique'))
       .pivot_table('score', index = ['player', 'unique_teams'], 
                    columns = 'game', aggfunc = 'sum', fill_value = '')
       .reset_index().rename_axis('', axis=1)
)
```

out

```
   player  unique_teams   101   102   103   104   105
0     Abe             1              12.0            
1   Brian             1                    10.0      
2  Claude             1                          12.0
3   Henry             2        22.0                  
4   James             3  30.0
```

Comment: Bingo! Thank you. This works, but can you explain why in the 'pivot_table' the data source is the 'score' column and not the original dataframe, df?

Comment: it means `values='score'` . /`pd.pivot_table(df, values='score',...)`(function) is same to `df.pivot_table(values='score', ...)` (method) / i think method is better than function becuz of chain method. chain method means, like my answer, `assign`-`pivot_table`-`reset_index`-`rename_axis` method of chain.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `groupby` and `nunique`

```
df.groupby('player')['team'].nunique()

player
Abe       1
Brian     1
Claude    1
Henry     2
James     3
```